# How to retrieve text from a textbox after a specific point in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, email

I am creating an email application in C#. I want to have an outlook style `To :` textbox in my program.

Basically, **I want the user to enter multiple email addresses and separate them with a comma.** Now how do I add all the email addresses from the textbox into an array.

For Example :

```
123@example.com,456@example.com
```

**How do I accomplish...**

- **Added them into a string array one by one.**

I know how to add text to a string array, but I cant figure out how to retrieve email addresses one by one.

Comment: Split the string using the separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string via a common seperator such as a comma (`,`)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string emailString = "email1@email.com,email2@email.com,   email3@email.com";

        string[] emails = emailString.Split(',');

        foreach (string email in emails)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(email);
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
email1@email.com
email2@email.com
  email3@email.com
```

Just take note that the user can enter in spaces in between the comma's and the email addresses. So you might have to do some normalization via the use of `String.trim(...)` to the strings to get rid of extra spaces (like `email3@email.com`)

Comment: @user3889649 if that worker than make sure you accept the answer. It will give you rep that will allow you to do more things on this site. It also lets others easily now an answer did work.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I joined recently so I didn't know what that meant. Anyway, I've accepted ur answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx_)  function:

```
  string emailString = @"123@example.com,456@example.com";

  //get the array
  string[] emails = emailString.Split(',');

  //or loop directly
  foreach(var email in emailString.Split(','))
  {

  }
```